# Passing Global Username in AppDelegate Swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, appdelegate

Following a lead to another question I posted I am now trying to declare a global username variable in the AppDelegate class in swift. My goal is to have a user put in his username in the startup screen and then have that username pop up on labels in other views - a universal username simply.

I have declared the username in my AppDelegate class

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var userName = ""

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

and in my main controller I have a label and a button function that sets the name

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var userLabel : UILabel!

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func setName (){ 
        appDelegate.userName = userLabel.text!;

    }
}
```

the idea is then that this name is to pop up in my player2 controller in its label

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Player2 : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var player2 : UILabel!

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.player2.text = appDelegate.userName as? String

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your code..everything is fine unless you want to get the value user typed in textfield after reopening your app..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one easy way to pass `userName` from one `ViewController` to another `ViewController`.

```
//Set your userName with specific key 
@IBAction func setName (){
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userLabel.text, forKey: "userName")
}
```

After that you can read that value this way from your `SecondViewController` this way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let userName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userName") as! String
    player2.text = "\(userName)"

}
```

You don't need to declare any variable into `AppDelegate` class.

Just get the value from `userLabel.text` in your `ViewController` class and store it. After that you can read it from `NSUserDefaults` anywhere in your project.

Comment: should i still bother with the appDelegate in these instances?

Comment: If you are reading username from label you don't need to declare anything into AppDelegate.

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

few solutions:

1. Use `NSUserDefaults` to store username
   in you AppDelegate:

   ```
   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
           NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("VitaliyGozhenko", forKey: "Username")
           return true
       }
   ```

In your UIViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    userLabel.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Username")
    }
```

2. Create separate class `User` which store username, email and other info related to user and add class property `[User currentUser]` to store current user information. After this you can access to current user information everywhere in the app

Create new class for `User` in new file User.swift:

```
import UIKit

class User: NSObject {

    static let currentUser = User()

    var username:String?
}
```

After that you can modify your AppDelegate:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            User.currentUser.username = "VitaliyGozhenko"
            return true
        }
```

In your UIViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    userLabel.text = User.currentUser.username
    }
```

Comment: thanks. should i declare these in the appDelegate or in my other views?

Comment: @Saucepan I edited my answer, so you can use code from it in your project

Comment: thank you again! could you perhaps elaborate a bit more on your second point as well? i am not able to get it ...

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko If I use your second option than that should I do when I that user Logged out?